# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of null? - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React Component

```
export default class CommentBox extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state ={
      showComments: false,
      comments: [
        { id: uuid.v4(), author: 'Clu', body: 'Just say no to love!', avatarUrl: 'images/default-avatar.png' },
        { id: uuid.v4(), author: 'Anne Droid', body: 'I wanna know what love is...', avatarUrl: 'images/default-avatar.png' }
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    const comments = this._getComments() || [];

    let commentList;
    if (this.state.showComments) {
      commentList = <div className="comment-list">{comments}</div>
    }

    return(
      <div className="comment-box">
        <h3>COMMENTS</h3>
        {this._getPopularMessage(comments.length)}
        <h4 className="comment-count">{this._getCommentsTitle(comments.length)}</h4>
        <button className="comment-toggle" onClick={this._toggleShowComments.bind(this)}>{this._toggleCommentButton()}</button>
        <CommentForm addComment={this._addComment.bind(this)}/>
        {commentList}
      </div>
    );
  }

  _addComment(author, body) {
    const comment = {
      id: uuid.v4(),
      author: author,
      body: body
    }

    this.setState({comments: this.state.comments.concat([comment])})
  }

  _getComments() {

    return this.state.comments.map((comment) => {
      return (<Comment
               author={comment.author}
               body={comment.body}
               avatarUrl={comment.avatarUrl}
               key={comment.id}
               onDelete = {this._deleteComment.bind(this, null, comment.id)}/>)
    });
  }
```

The main issue...
If I leave out `event.stopPropagation`, when I run this and click the 'Delete Comment' link, everything works as expected. However, when I add it in, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of null`. I assume the `onClick` event in the Comment component (see bottom code box), is not passing the event through. Is there any way to rectify this?

```
  _deleteComment(event, key) {
    event.stopPropagation()
    console.log(key)
    this.setState (
      {comments: this.state.comments.filter((singleComment) => singleComment.id !== key)
      }
    )
    console.log(this.state.comments)
  }
}
```

For reference, the Comment component:
I tried binding(this) to `onDelete` e.g. `<a className="comment-actions-delete" href="#" onClick={this.props.onDelete.bind(this)}>Delete comment</a>` but it didn't seem to work.

```
export default class Comment extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isAbusive: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    let commentBody;
    if (!this.state.isAbusive) {
      commentBody = this.props.body;
    } else {
      commentBody = <em>Content marked as abusive</em>;
    }
    return(
      <div className="comment">
        <p className="comment-header">{this.props.author}</p>
        <p className="comment-body">
          {commentBody}
        </p>
        <div className="comment-actions">
          <VotingButtons />
          <a className="comment-actions-delete" href="#" onClick={this.props.onDelete}>Delete comment</a>
          <a className="comment-actions-abuse" href="#" onClick={this._toggleAbuse.bind(this)}>Report as abuse</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  _toggleAbuse(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.setState({isAbusive: !this.state.isAbusive})
  }
}
```

Comment: can you sanitize your code samples a bit to stick to relevant parts of the code?

Comment: Thanks, is that better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be that you have a typo?

```
 this.setState (
 {coments: this.state.comments.filter((singleComment) => singleComment.id !== key)
      }
```

vs

```
commentList = <div className="comment-list">{comments}</div>
```

In other words, you are setting 'coments' but retrieving 'comments'.